# Trim text in a cell of bootstrap table

Tags: javascript, python, html, django, twitter-bootstrap

How can I trim text in a cell of bootstrap table?

Example: In bootstrap table below I have big names in 'stock name' column, this messes formatting of my entire table for example (check columns like invested amount, gains etc).

Can I give fixed length to content in stock name column ? By default it can show "Ajanta Ph...", OnHover of a cell it can show full name.

[image]

I am injecting this page from Django template.

```
<tr id="port_row_{{row.stock}}_{{index}}">
   {% if row.stock == 'TOTAL'%}
   <td> {{row.stock}}</td>
   {% else %}
   <td> <a target="_blank" style="color:blue;" href="https://www.google.com/finance?q=NSE:{{ row.stock }}">{{row.stock}}</a></td>
   {% endif %}
   <td>{{row.name}}</td>
   <td>{{row.monday_open_price|intcomma}}</td>
   <td>{{row.previous_close|intcomma}}</td>
   <td>
      {% if row.price >= row.previous_close %}
      <div style="color:green">
         {{row.price|intcomma}}
      </div>
      {% else %}
      <div style="color:red">
         {{row.price|intcomma}}
      </div>
      {% endif %}
   </td>
   <td> &#x20b9; {{row.investment_amount|intcomma}}</td>
   <td>
      {% if row.weekly_gain >= 0 %}
      <div style="color:green">
         {{row.weekly_gain|intcomma}}
         <i class="fa fa-arrow-up"></i>
      </div>
      {% else %}
      <div style="color:tomato">
         {{row.weekly_gain|intcomma}}
         <i class="fa fa-arrow-down"></i>
      </div>
      {% endif %}
   </td>
   <td>
      {% if row.daily_gain >= 0 %}
      <div style="color:green">
         {{row.daily_gain|intcomma}}
         <i class="fa fa-arrow-up"></i>
      </div>
      {% else %}
      <div style="color:tomato">
         {{row.daily_gain|intcomma}}
         <i class="fa fa-arrow-down"></i>
      </div>
      {% endif %}
   </td>
   <td> &#x20b9; {{row.current_market_value|intcomma}}</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Can you show the (relevant parts of the) template?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Added in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of the [**`|truncatechars`** template filter [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#truncatechars):

```
<td>{{ row.name|truncatechars:9 }}</td>
```

This will thus limit the number of characters to nine (in this case). If the name is shorter than or has exactly nine characters, then it will render the name. Otherwise it will render the first characters, followed by an ellipsis (…).

You can make use of [*Bootstrap's tooltips](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/tooltips/) and add a tooltip like:

```
<td>
    <span data-toggle="tooltip" title="{{ row.name }}">
    {{ row.name|truncatechars:9 }}
    </span>
</td>
```

Comment: Thanks, it does truncate. But it would have been useful if I can show full name on a tip when user hovers over name. Is this possible?